# Synchronise a large quantity of small files over a slow connection

Tags: vpn, network-attached-storage

I have 4 NAS devices on a VPN with 164,000,000,000 files on these devices that I need to synchronize.
The folder that I need to synchronize (as close to live as practical) contains 39,000 files and the rest of the folders could be replicated as little as once a day.
These files are updated or created locally on the storage devices.
The problem is I only have a maximum of 1Mb bandwidth to do this through. I have tried a few solutions but the choke point is that each solution needs to compare all the files from one end which means scanning the drive contents over the VPN.
The files are cad files and PDF files so they are quite small and only about 10mb of data an hour needs to be transferred but the scanning of the drive chokes the connection.
Does anybody know of a solution that I can put on each end that scans the devises locally for changes then just pushes the change?

Comment: Are you synchronizing in both directions?

Comment: Yes I need two way synchronization.

Comment: rsync is about as fast as you can get, then. You'd be better served by increasing the available bandwidth.

Comment: Better bandwidth sure would be great but unfortunately its not an option.

Comment: I'm looking for something that looks for changes locally then pushes the updates.